# php - function require-once can't find file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am implementing a code where visitors can email our company.

in my gmail.php, it has this code for line 11

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php') or exit();
```

the error it gives is when i run it is

```
Warning: require_once(1) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maxsell/public_html/php/gmail.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '1' (include_path='/home/maxsell/php:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/maxsell/public_html/php/gmail.php on line 11
```

and if i click on `[function.require-once]` it loads

```
The requested URL /php/function.require-once was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I made this in our other website and it worked there. I tried changing file path in `require_once` but it doesn't work. gmail.php and PHPMailerAutoload.php is in the same folder.

edit: here is a directory contents
[directory contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWGmJ.png)

Comment: This is because may be your file is not on the location. Please specify the proper file path.

Comment: `PHPMailerAutoload.php` this file is not there in the current working directory (means where this code resist your phpmailer file is not there) .Try to provide full path of that file

Comment: you don't have to `or exit()` after require, since it automatically aborts the script itself on failure. also: are you sure your file is called exactly `PHPMailerAutoload.php`? AFAICR, case matters

Comment: It is the file not found. Not the function i.e. wrong title of thread.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes its `PHPMailerAutoload.php` I checked again. It's in the same folder as gmail.php but for some reason php can't find it. @S.I. ill change the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `or exit()`-part.

when i use

```
require_once("test.php") or exit();
```

i get the same error, but

```
require_once("test.php");
```

works if the file exists, or throws a correct error if it doesn't.

also, the common syntax is

```
require_once "test.php";
```

and the `or exit()` part is superfluous anyway, since require quits the script itself if the file is not found.

**edit:**

after some testing i suspect that the internal workings of this curious error is that require_once is not a function but a command structure, meaning that

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php') or exit();
```

is functionally the same as

```
require_once ('PHPMailerAutoload.php' or exit());
```

since the `or`-operator takes precedence.

which makes your require fail because `('PHPMailerAutoload.php' or exit())` resolves to `true`, effectively making php try to `require(true)` which must fail.

Comment: The reason why I put the `or exit() ` is that the page took too long to respond. I thought I could find what is wrong when i put the `or exit()`.

Comment: I removed `or exit()` again it the page took too long to respond. This code works when I use it in xampp and in other website

Comment: I contacted our webhost but I'm not quite sure what was the problem so I wasnt able to ask specific question to them

Comment: well, the problem you described in your question is caused by the or exit(). which, in that place, wouldn't do anything, anyway. if your page times out, probably you have an infinite loop somewhere, but that's a different question.

Comment: you do that. but if my answer solved the problem of this question, please accept it so it can be found quicker in the future if someone else searches for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one and hope this will work for you

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phpmailerfoldername/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Comment: ok will try that. I will change `DOCUMENT_ROOT' and `phpmailerfoldername`